# Grails <=====> compile ":ajax-uploader:1.1"

Tags: java, ajax, grails, upload

how use this plugin in grails application?? I have exceptions :

**In Config.groovy**

```
imageUpload {
    temporaryFile = "webapp/images" // Path to where files will be uploaded
  }
```

**In Index.gsp**

```
<head><r:require module="fileuploader" /></head>

<body>

<uploader:uploader id="yourUploaderId">
   <uploader:onComplete>
        $('statusDiv').update('Thank you for uploading the file ');  
  </uploader:onComplete>
</uploader:uploader>

</body>
```

**ExceptionS:**

| Error 2014-02-03 12:22:57,386 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR ajaxuploader.AjaxUploadController - Failed to upload file. Message: java.io.FileNotFoundException: web-app\images\avatars (Accès refusé) Line | Method ->> 14 | upload in uk.co.desirableobjects.ajaxuploader.AjaxUploaderService

| 22 | doCall in uk.co.desirableobjects.ajaxuploader.AjaxUploadController$_closure1 | 195 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter | 63 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter | 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor | 615 | run in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker ^ 744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread Caused by FileNotFoundException: web-app\images\avatars (Accès refusé) ->> 221 | in java.io.FileOutputStream

| 12 | upload in uk.co.desirableobjects.ajaxuploader.AjaxUploaderService | 22 | doCall . in uk.co.desirableobjects.ajaxuploader.AjaxUploadController$_closure1 | 195 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter | 63 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter | 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor | 615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker ^ 744 | run in java.lang.Thread

Comment: Some more code would be useful.

Comment: It seems you are trying to upload the file at web-app\images\avatars and you don't have enough permissions to write in this folder.

Comment: thank you for reply but i don't use any user to upload !!

Comment: but in your server you need to set up proper permissions to write in the folder.